# jQuery: make two divs same height on window resize

Tags: jquery

I know this has been asked a few time and I got the solution from one of the questions asked here. It works just fine on page load but what I can't get to work is on window resize. The divs stay the same height resulting in the content inside overflowing.

```
$(document).ready(function(){

  function setboxHeight(){
    var box1height = $('.box1').height();
    var box2height = $('.box2').height();    
    box1height>box2height ? ($('.box2').height(box1height)):($('.box1').height(box2height));    
  }

    setboxHeight();

  $(window).resize(function(){
    setboxHeight();
  });

});
```

Here is the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/fbthuemc/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

May I ask is this what you want to?

```
function setboxHeight(){
        $('.box1, .box2').css('height', '');
        ...
  }
```

Now it looks that it can reset the box1's height while you resizing the window.
http://jsfiddle.net/fbthuemc/3/

By the way, I usually use `console.log()` to observe elements' height numbers etc.

Answer (score 2):

I think this is what you are after.

http://jsfiddle.net/7r1ekt9x/

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  function setboxHeight() {
    // Get the height of box1
    var box1height = $('.box1').height();
    // Set box2 height equal to box1
    $('.box2').height(box1height)
  }

  setboxHeight();

  $(window).resize(function() {
    setboxHeight();
  });
});
```

Comment: This works only if I know which box will be greater in height.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you want to do. Avoid overflow? If so, you can set the `overflow: hidden` of them.
Or show y scrollbars `overflow-y: auto; overflow-x: hidden;` (or inverse).

Also you can set the `height: 100% !important;` to force it. You can also use:     `word-wrap: break-word;` to avoid words getting out of margin.

Other thing you can do, is to set the `min-height` and/or `max-height` so you don´t get unexpected visual issues.

Hope that helps!

Comment: On window resize, I want to reset the height of the box with the greater content and make the second box the same height. There should not be empty space below the content in the box which has more content (if window size is increased) and should not have text overflow (if window size is decreased).

Comment: How about adding a class `.boxes {display:block; overflow:hidden; word-wrap: break-word;}` to box boxes, and then `$(window).resize(function(){$( ".box2" ).height($( ".box1" ).height());});`